# Get all Fields within Collection of Objects

Tags: apex

I am trying to find all fields included in a collection of objects, but am running into issues because of null values not displaying within the results. The queried fields are not known ahead of time, so it isn't as easy as just making a list of the known fields.

As an example, if I receive a collection like this:

```
User:{Id=12345, Name=Name1}
User:{Id=23456, Name=Name2, aNewField=abc}
User:{Id=34567, Name=Name3, yetAnotherField=def}
```

What is the most efficient way to get a list of all of the fields like so:
{Id, Name, aNewField, yetAnotherField}

I would prefer to not loop through each result as there may be quite a few in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as follows in Apex using [getPopulatedFieldsAsMap](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_getPopulatedFieldsAsMap)

```
Set<String> populatedFields = new Set<String>();
for (SObject sobject: sobjects) {
    populatedFields.add(sobject.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap().keySet());
}
```

Will return all non-null fields from any list of sObjects